# Python pandas difference of specific rows in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform, apply

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Firm': ['Firm1','Firm1','Firm1','Firm1','Firm1','Firm1','Firm2','Firm2','Firm2','Firm2','Firm2','Firm2'],'Location' : ['Country1', 'Country1', 'Country1', 'Country2', 'Country2', 'Country2','Country1', 'Country1', 'Country1', 'Country2', 'Country2', 'Country2'], 'Currency' : ['Curr1', 'Curr2', 'Curr3', 'Curr1', 'Curr2', 'Curr3','Curr1', 'Curr2', 'Curr3', 'Curr1', 'Curr2', 'Curr3'], 'Value' : [100, 105, 110, 100, 95, 120, 95, 110, 115, 105, 120, 90] })
```

which looks like this:

df:

```
     Firm  Location Currency  Value
0   Firm1  Country1    Curr1    100
1   Firm1  Country1    Curr2    105
2   Firm1  Country1    Curr3    110
3   Firm1  Country2    Curr1    100
4   Firm1  Country2    Curr2     95
5   Firm1  Country2    Curr3    120
6   Firm2  Country1    Curr1     95
7   Firm2  Country1    Curr2    110
8   Firm2  Country1    Curr3    115
9   Firm2  Country2    Curr1    105
10  Firm2  Country2    Curr2    120
11  Firm2  Country2    Curr3     90
```

Now I would like to calculate the difference between Curr3 and Curr2 (of column Value) for each Firm-Location group and change the value of Curr3 based on the outcome. The resulting df should then look like this:

```
     Firm  Location Currency  Value
0   Firm1  Country1    Curr1    100
1   Firm1  Country1    Curr2    105
2   Firm1  Country1    Curr3      5
3   Firm1  Country2    Curr1    100
4   Firm1  Country2    Curr2     95
5   Firm1  Country2    Curr3     25
6   Firm2  Country1    Curr1     95
7   Firm2  Country1    Curr2    110
8   Firm2  Country1    Curr3      5
9   Firm2  Country2    Curr1    105
10  Firm2  Country2    Curr2    120
11  Firm2  Country2    Curr3    -30
```

I have tried using `.groupby` and `.apply` which gives me the results, however I would like to do the transformation in the original dataframe.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Firm','Location']).apply(lambda g: g[g.Currency == 'Curr3'].Value.values[0] - g[g.Currency == 'Curr2'].Value.values[0])
```

df2:

```
Firm    Location    0
Firm1   Country1    5
Firm1   Country2    25
Firm2   Country1    5
Firm2   Country2    -30
```

I cannot figure out how to do this inplace in the original df. I also tried the same this using `.transform`, however it creates an error:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Firm','Location']).transform(lambda g: g[g.Currency == 'Curr3'].Value.values[0] - g[g.Currency == 'Curr2'].Value.values[0])

AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'Currency'", 'occurred at index Currency')
```

**---- Update based on Erfan's solution:**

```
newvals = (
    df.where(df['Currency'].isin(['Curr2', 'Curr3']))
      .groupby(['Firm', 'Location'])['Value'].diff()
)
df['Value'] = newvals.fillna(df['Value'])
```

If df looks like this however (Currency not sorted), the solution no longer works (as diff() only calculates the difference to the previous value

```
    Firm    Location    Currency    Value
0   Firm1   Country1    Curr2   100
1   Firm1   Country1    Curr1   105
2   Firm1   Country1    Curr3   110
3   Firm1   Country2    Curr3   100
4   Firm1   Country2    Curr2   95
5   Firm1   Country2    Curr1   120
6   Firm2   Country1    Curr1   95
7   Firm2   Country1    Curr2   110
8   Firm2   Country1    Curr3   115
9   Firm2   Country2    Curr2   105
10  Firm2   Country2    Curr3   120
11  Firm2   Country2    Curr1   90
```

-> result:

```
    Firm    Location    Currency    Value
0   Firm1   Country1    Curr2   100.0
1   Firm1   Country1    Curr1   105.0
2   Firm1   Country1    Curr3   10.0
3   Firm1   Country2    Curr3   100.0
4   Firm1   Country2    Curr2   -5.0
5   Firm1   Country2    Curr1   120.0
6   Firm2   Country1    Curr1   95.0
7   Firm2   Country1    Curr2   110.0
8   Firm2   Country1    Curr3   5.0
9   Firm2   Country2    Curr2   105.0
10  Firm2   Country2    Curr3   15.0
11  Firm2   Country2    Curr1   90.0
```

Now, it is no longer the case that each time the difference between Curr3 and Curr 2 is calculated and replaces the value for Curr3.

Comment: I saw your edit, will update answer when Im home

Answer (score 2):

Using `DataFrame.where`, `Series.isin`, `GroupBy.diff` and `Series.fillna`:

First we convert all `Curr1` to `NaN` with `where`, then we groupby on `Firm` and `Location` and calculate the difference in `Value`.

```
newvals = (
    df.where(df['Currency'].isin(['Curr2', 'Curr3']))
      .groupby(['Firm', 'Location'])['Value'].diff()
)
df['Value'] = newvals.fillna(df['Value'])
```

```
     Firm  Location Currency  Value
0   Firm1  Country1    Curr1  100.0
1   Firm1  Country1    Curr2  105.0
2   Firm1  Country1    Curr3    5.0
3   Firm1  Country2    Curr1  100.0
4   Firm1  Country2    Curr2   95.0
5   Firm1  Country2    Curr3   25.0
6   Firm2  Country1    Curr1   95.0
7   Firm2  Country1    Curr2  110.0
8   Firm2  Country1    Curr3    5.0
9   Firm2  Country2    Curr1  105.0
10  Firm2  Country2    Curr2  120.0
11  Firm2  Country2    Curr3  -30.0
```

Comment: Great that did exactly what I wanted! Many thanks for your very quick solution! However, the .diff() only calculates the difference to the previous item along an axis. Imagine a situation in which you would want to take the differences for more than one pair of rows which are not necessarily adjacent (e.g. Curr2-Curr3 and Curr 3-Curr1). Or if you would like to specify which Value to subtract from which (Curr2-Curr3 instead of vice versa). How would you implement this?

Comment: Can you edit, or add another example of dataset where my current solution fails. I think I understand what you mean, but it's always better to be sure, so I will provide a sufficient solution.